# RANKX show same rank number against different values

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

I have been creating a dashboard in which i am using RANKX but it is not working according to my need.

**Scenario :**  I have table which have four column (you can see in the attached image):

1). Community English name 
2). Building_Total_area 
3). rank_m 4). area_rank

I want to calculate the rank on the basis of "Building_Total_area" so i create a two measure :

Measure 1 : 
`rank_m = sum(Building_Summary_Information[building_total_area])`

Measure 2 : 
`area_rank = RANKX(ALL(Building_Summary_Information),[rank_m],,ASC)`

Problem = Rank numbers are not correct. It show same rank number against different values. (please see the attached image)

What should i do ?

Thanks,[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
rank_m:=SUM(Bulding_Summary_Information[bulding_total_area])
```

```
area_rank:=RANKX(ALL(Bulding_Summary_Information[community_Name_english]),[rank_m],,DESC)
```

The result is this:
[image]